# How do I retrieve VCS Changes from inside a TeamCity build runner plugin?

Tags: teamcity

I'm writing a build `runner plugin`for TeamCity.

As of right now, I intend the build plugin to be triggered by a `VCS change`. After trigger, the plugin looks at the files that have been changed and decides which projects to build.

Is there a way to retrieve the changed files from within the build plugin?

I'm not opposed to moving this logic into a trigger plugin if you think that makes more sense, but I would have similar questions in that regard as well.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out this TeamCity plugin.

I should probably mention, I am an absolute beginner.

I've posted my code on github, https://github.com/bulldiser/SmartBuild.

I can't get Smart Build to be added as a build runner type. Can anyone see why?

Answer (score 0):

Build property `%system.teamcity.build.changedFiles.file%` contains the full path of a file with a list of the changes.  According to the documentation at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Risk+Tests+Reordering+in+Custom+Test+Runner the format of the file is:

```
<relative file path>:<change type>:<revision>
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like good information. It will take me some time to get to the point where I can ensure this solves my problem, but I don't see why it wouldn't.

Any tips on debugging the plugin? I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE.

Comment: I don't have experience with IntelliJ or with debugging plugins so I'm afraid I can't help with that.